# СSS и HTML. Как реализовать линии?

Tags: css, вёрстка

Как проще всего с помощью CSS и HTML реализовать линии, обведенные желтым?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.modal-dialog {
  width: 1000px;
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #c2c2c2;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
}

.modal-title {
  text-align: left;
}

.sound {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.question {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}

.sound_title {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.sound_desc {
  color: #010100;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 18px;
  padding: 15px 10px 0px 30px;
}

.sound_title:before {
  content: '';
  width: 20px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.aim {
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
}

.modal-title {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.aim_desc {
  color: #010100;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 18px;
  padding: 15px 25px 0px 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <div class="title modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><span class="title_span title_modal">ПОДРОБНЕЕ</span> О ДВЕРИ</div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="sound">
      <div class="sound_title">ПРЕВОСХОДНАЯ ЗВУКОИЗОЛЯЦИЯ</div>
      <div class="sound_desc">двухкомпонентный пенополиуретан высокой плотности служит лучшим термосберегающим наполнителем. Данный материал равномерно заполняет все полотно и при застывании в горячих прессах связывается со всеми элементами, образуя единый моноблок и термозащиту.
        А также хорошо поглощает звуковые волны благодаря своим физическим свойствам. (Волна звука гасится в пузырьках пены)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="question">
      <div class="quest_titile title"><span class="title_span quest_span">ОСТАЛИСЬ</span> ВОПРОСЫ?</div>
      <div class="quest_input">
        <form class="form-inline" action="/action_page.php">
          <input type="name" id="email" placeholder="ИМЯ" name="email">
          <input class="phone_clear" type="phone" id="pwd" placeholder="ТЕЛЕФОН" name="pswd">
          <button class="submit_form" type="submit">ОТПРАВИТЬ</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sound aim">
      <div class="sound_title aim_title">ЦЕЛЬНАЯ КОНСТРУКЦИЯ</div>
      <div class="sound_desc aim_desc">Дверной блок выполнен по бессварной технологии на высокоточном оборудовании - цельногнутая конструкция. Полотно не имеет сварных швов (основная точка коррозии).</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: С помощью псевдоэлементов `before` и `after`

Comment: Во многом зависит как сверстанно все остальное. Добавьте Ваш текущий HTML и СSS

Answer (score 0):

```
    .modal-content:after{
    content: ".";
    color: #ff000000;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 2px;
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: 500px;
}
.modal-content:before{
    content: ".";
    color: #ff000000;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 580px;
    height: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 149px;
    left: 8px
}

 .modal-header:after{

        content: ".";
    color: #ff000000;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 580px;
    height: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 428px;
}
```